# Camera Issue on IOS with Angular PWA

Tags: angular, iphone, camera, progressive-web-apps

I have an Angular PWA installed on the iPhone, for the first time when I try to access the Camera, it works perfectly but once I close the app (I swipe the app screen up) and open it again the Camera goes completely black and stops to work.

Does anybody have any idea what can be the Solution for such a problem??

I have thought about killing the process manually but there is no app to do so, after I turn off the iPhone and turn it on again, it works like the first time.

Side Note:

- The App has permission to access the Camera, so it is not a matter of permission.